# Scriptable mp3 player similar to niftyplayer

Tags: php, javascript, mp3

Does anyone know of a scriptable mp3 player similar to niftyplayer?  niftyplayer does exactly what I need, but the code is old (2003) and seems broken. It had one flash .swf and a .js file with functions for controlling the player.

I am looking for an mp3 player where I could call functions such as play(), stop(), load(file.mp3), loadandplay(file.mp3).

niftyplayer did this.

```
    <a href="javascript:niftyplayer('niftyPlayer1').playToggle()">play toggle</a>
    (or
    <a href="javascript:niftyplayer('niftyPlayer1').play()">play</a>
    |
    <a href="javascript:niftyplayer('niftyPlayer1').pause()">pause</a>
    )
    <a href="javascript:niftyplayer('niftyPlayer1').stop()">stop</a>
    <br />
    <a href="javascript:niftyplayer('niftyPlayer1').load('betty.mp3')">load file 1</a>
    |
    <a href="javascript:niftyplayer('niftyPlayer1').load('creeeeak.mp3')">load file 2</a>
    |
    <a href="javascript:niftyplayer('niftyPlayer1').loadAndPlay('creeeeak.mp3')">load file 2 and play it</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you had a look at [JPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/)? It can be used as an MP3 player, and is HTML5 compatible. Also, there are [a bunch of methods](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/) for controlling it.

Comment: Yes I did but I was looking for something simpler similar to niftyplayer.

Comment: Ah right. I'm interested to see what other people come up with, although you can make JPlayer as complex or as simple as you want, really.